# Adding Windows Live ID to the credential store

Tags: c#, .net, credentials, webdav

I have written an application that maps a user's SkyDrive to a network drive.
However when opening word documents directly from the network drive, Microsoft Office 2010 tries to load the document using WebDav and prompts for the  user to login in again.

[image]

When you login it works fine, and if you click "Remember Me" it stores the credentials in the credential store, accessible via `rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr`
This only lasts until the session is closed.

I want to incorporate the automatic storing of the user's credentials into my program so that the user doesn't get prompted at all.

I have tried using the CredWrite API however that only allows me to store generic credentials. I need to store a (.Net Passport) credential.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375187(v=vs.85).aspx

I have only been able to achieve this using the CredUIPromptForCredentials API with the flags set to CREDUI_FLAGS_SERVER_CREDENTIAL
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375177(v=vs.85).aspx

I have inspected the API call that word makes to credui.dll and it is identical to the one I am calling (aside from some captions).

[image]

[image]

But it produces different results.
My code produces this credential to be saved

[image]

The word api call/subsequent code produces this credential

[image]

However I cannot figure out how to get the credential target to save correctly so that office will load it without prompting. I'd prefer to even have the prompt load if there is no option as I can pre fill the username and password so that the user just has to click OK but I'd like to do it silently.

Additionally if there is anyway to disable word's WebDav support/force it to use the network drive as an actual network drive that would also work. I have been unable to find any answer. If anyone has any idea I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: In your screenshots the target are different. Can you change it in your object property `pszTargetName`?